# Android in-app update says update not available, although I can see the new version in the app store

Tags: android

When using internal app sharing, the in-app update flow works great. As soon as I can see an "update" in the play store from the internal app link - the app can detect the new version.

I can't for the life of me get in-app updates to work in production. The calls just return `availableVersionCode` as 0 and claims there are no app updates available.

However - I can see a newer version in the play store and the play store has the "Update" button (as opposed to the "Open" button). I've cleared the cache, restarted the phone, tried two different devices , done a factory reset, and have waited 48 hours.... still no dice.

Why would the exact same code work with internal app sharing but not in the production play store? This is so frustrating. Thanks for any help.

Is there a possible work-around or more stable flow?

````
// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

// Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
      Toast.makeText(this, appUpdateInfo.toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yes available2!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
          appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
                  // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
                  appUpdateInfo,
                  // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
                  AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
                  // The current activity making the update request.
                  this,
                  // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
                  1337);

          // Request the update.
        } catch  (Exception e) {
          Log.e("update error", "update error", e);

        }
      }
    });```
````

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Posted in an edit